# Getting response using "POST" method from .net server(C# with json format) to Objective-c issue

Tags: c#, android, ios, objective-c

Hi I am a iOS Developer,

Past 2 days onwards i am facing one issue like: In my .net developer provided me one API for getting response using **POST method only** not **GET**

**Step 1:** 
   **Here i use my Objective-C code**

```
-(void)getUserNameStr: (NSString*)newUsername withPassword: (NSString*)newPassword{
NSString*urlStr = @"http://taxi.expertverification.com/api/v1/ValidUser?";
NSString * myRequestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UserName=%@&Password=%@",
                       urlStr,
                       newUsername,
                       newPassword];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
//post section
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myRequestString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
            // handle response
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);

        }] resume];
}
```

**My Response is:**

```
requestReply: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

**Step 2 : Android Code**

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    Log.d(TAG, "ba1: "+ba1);


  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", "rkb");
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "rkb");



    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://taxi.expertverification.com/api/v1/ValidUser?";

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();               

        String outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

        Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection";

        bitmapOrg.recycle();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
```

**My Response is :**

```
true
```

means i am getting proper response here

In Android i am getting response currectly but in iOS i am not getting Why?

Here i used some other 3rd party SDK's also like : AFNetworking, SBJson also but still i am facing same issue can you plz help me out regarding this issue

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The api is misused. The data task should init with url request when using post method. HTTP body should store post data. By the way, you may need to disable app transport security in iOS9, if the server do not support https (https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa).

```
-(void)getUserNameStr: (NSString*)newUsername withPassword: (NSString*)newPassword{
    NSString*urlStr = @"http://taxi.expertverification.com/api/v1/ValidUser";
    NSString * myRequestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&Password=%@",
                                 newUsername,
                                 newPassword];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    //post section
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    // handle response
                    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);

                }] resume];
}
```

Comment: ThanQ.., It's perfect solution to me