# Getting Image response using "POST" method from .net server to objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry to ask the same/related question again

Today Morning i posted one question in [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34714595/4720315) and i got the correct response also and my problem also solved.

In the same case in my .net developer created one more API for uploading user profile pic. I followed same guidelines and i did code also

but i am getting an error:

**Here i posted my Code like::**

```
- (void)getLoginUserId:(NSString*)newUserId withUploadImageData: (NSString*)newImageData;
{
    NSString*urlStr =  @"http://taxi.expertverification.com/api/v1/Getimage";
    NSString * myRequestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&imageget=%@",
                             newUserId,
                             newImageData];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    //post section
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                // handle response
                NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
            }] resume];
}
```

**Calling a method is::**

```
 [self getLoginUserId:@"121"
  withUploadImageData:@"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"];
```

**My Response is:**

```
requestReply: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Parameter is not valid.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
at RKB.RestAPI.V1Controller.insertimages(getimage _get) in d:\\Projects\\RKB_RestAPI\\V1.cs:line 568
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
```

But If i run this API using **ANDROID** i am getting proper response

**ANDROID Code is:**

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
Log.d(TAG, "ba1: "+ba1);


  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", "121");
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imageget", "same as my image data");



try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://taxi.expertverification.com/api/v1/Getimage";

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();               

    String outPut = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    Log.i("GET RESPONSE—-", outPut);

    Log.e("log_tag ******", "good connection";

    bitmapOrg.recycle();
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag ******", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
}
```

Code(for ANDROID) is same as i posted morning.

If you don't mind can you please help me out regarding this

Comment: Please provide the relevant Android code that is supposedly working with the same inputs. Running the request directly with curl results in the same error, so the issue is not in the Objective-C code, but somehow in the contents of the data.

Comment: I edited my question, Please check it out once, I already done this in Eclips, i am getting proper response

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the exact same image data? That's what the server is choking on...

Comment: Yes i am very sure, Image data is same(Android/iOS) currently we are using hard code data only(for testing purpose)..

Comment: I seriously doubt it. Using the same image data in curl results in the same error. Using another image works. It's the image data that the server does not like, for some reason.

Comment: No @jcaron, Past few day's onwards my .net developer& me workout on that but the problem is not persist yet. That's the reason only Today morning i asked him to create one demo API(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714595/getting-response-using-post-method-from-net-serverc-with-json-format-to-ob) i posted here also, for getting normal data it's fine... Now i am fully concentrated on image data issue sir, The problem is===> in Android side response is coming perfectly but not in iOS side..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100361/discussion-between-mannam-brahmam-and-jcaron).

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you need to URL-encode the base64 data before assembling the form data (it's full of `+`s which decode to spaces, not `+`s).

Possible options:

- use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` (making sure you include `+` in the characters to be escaped) or `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` to escape the data (before assembling)
- use some existing library that will do that for you
- switch to a different format that is easier to manipulate, such as JSON

This is the category I personally use for URL-escaping data:

**NSString+urlencode.h**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (urlencode)

- (NSString *)escapedValueForURLParameter;

@end
```

**NSString+urlencode.m**:

```
#import "NSString+urlencode.h"

@implementation NSString (urlencode)

- (NSString *)escapedValueForURLParameter
{
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)
        CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                NULL,
                                                (__bridge CFStringRef) self,
                                                NULL,
                                                (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8
                                            );
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is easy to solve this by using AFNetworking

It will simplify the process for your considerably and save you a lot of time. It is widely used framework by developers.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

You can easily send image with parameters using just few lines (POST-multipart request):

For Example Check this code.(Make sure you refer the above link and add the appropriate header files)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: ThanQ for you're suggestion, But as per my concern currently i am using iOS 9, Apple Developers did great job(they simplified no.of concepts) for proving response(POST/GET) in simple way only, why should i use 3rd party SDK's

Comment: And more over i am dynamically fetch images from Gallery/Take photo, how can i get URL path from that